# Cavity Flow CFD Boundary conditions and strange waves

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics

So I have a PDE that I use to describe how material flows through a volume(2D or 3D).
$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + \vec{u} \cdot \nabla C = (D' + D )\nabla^2C$$
Now using finite differences I get to the following:
$$C^{i+1}_{j,k} =C^i_{j,k}+\Delta t \biggr[ (D+D')\biggr[\frac{C^i_{j+1,k}-2C^i_{j,k}+C^i_{j-1,k}}{(\Delta x)^2}+\frac{C^i_{j,k+1}-2C^i_{j,k}+C^i_{j,k-1}}{(\Delta y)^2}\biggr]-u_x \frac{C^i_{j,k} -C^i_{j-1,k}}{\Delta x} - u_y \frac{C^i_{j,k} -C^i_{j,k-1}}{\Delta y}\biggr]$$
where D is diffusion coefficient and superscript is temporal, subscript is spatial. (Just imagine a grid). We are given $u_x$ and $u_y$ through some already validated code. Now, we use a boundary condition where $C=0$ at the edges. I know this is a silly boundary condition but it's irrelevant because the problem I'm about to show you persists even if we use small times.(where the concentration doesn't reach the edge)

[image]

[Look in the comments...It's telling me I can't post 2 links... Where do I have the second?]

here is the code. It's relatively simple.

> ```
> import numpy as np 
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> import time
> %matplotlib inline
> from scipy import ndimage
> import scipy.io as sio
> a =sio.loadmat('C:\\Users\\Tsila elbag\\Documents\\IPythonNotes\\New folder\\Cavity10k_1.mat')
> b = a['VelField']
> N =50
> M =300
> ux = b[0][0][0]
> uy = b[0][0][1]
> #ux = np.zeros((50,50))
> #uy = np.ones((50,50))
> dx = 2/N
> dy =2/N
> D= .001
> Dprime =0
> dt = .0001
> C = np.zeros((N,N))
> #C[np.floor((.25+1)/dx):np.floor((.75+1)/dx),np.floor((.25+1)/dy)\
> #  :np.floor((.75+1)/dy)]=1
> C[np.floor((.25+1)/dy)\
>   :np.floor((.75+1)/dy),.1/dx:np.floor((.25)/dx)]=1
> f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
> axarr[0].contourf(C)
> Chist= C
> Ctemp = C
> for T in range(M):
>     for j in range(N):
>         for k in range(N):
>             if k==49  or j ==49 or k ==0 or j ==0:
>                 Ctemp[j,k]=0
>             else:
>
>                 Ctemp[j,k]= C[j,k]+dt*((D+Dprime)*(((C[j+1,k]-2*C[j,k]+\
>                 C[j-1,k])/(dx**2))+((C[j,k+1]-2*C[j,k]+C[j,k-1])/(dy**2)))-\
>                 ux[j,k]*(C[j,k]-C[j-1,k])/(dx)-uy[j,k]*(C[j,k]-C[j,k-1])/dy)
>     #Chist.append(list(C))
>     C = Ctemp    
> axarr[0].set_title('Original') axarr[2].contourf(C)
> axarr[2].set_title('{} seconds later'.format(dt*M))
> ```

So the question is why do I have these waves and if anyone knows effective boundary conditions I would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't add the picture until I'm 10 reputation. If you up-vote twice. I will put the image.

Comment: Despite your question at the end, it is not clear to me what you are asking. Programming is *off topic* on this site, and I don't see what it has got to do with a question about physics. So I do not understand what your question is asking about physics. You seem to be asking about your coding.

Comment: With a picture of the waves, it's possible to give a physical explanation to it -- but odds are good it's a numerical problem. We will have to wait and see what the problem actually is.

Comment: I just flagged it! Thanks! I didn't know that that stack Exchange existed.

Comment: I have 2 possible explanations. (a) You're writing `dy=2/N`, but bot `2` and `N` are integers, so `dy` might be `0` in that case. Try something like `dy=2.0/N`. The same goes for `dx`. (b) The problem might also be with your input velocity field `ux` & `uy`. Try (a), if that doesn't work, take a look at the velocity field.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about debugging specific code.

Comment: @HaykHakobyan dy and dx are floats and the input velocity field has been verified. Thanks for looking. :)

Comment: Are you using a value of $\frac{u\Delta t}{\Delta x}>1$?